# __repr__ in the child class doesn't show all it arguments, is that a normal practice?

Tags: python, oop

I try to learn OOP from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ej_02ICOIgs&t=143s&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org

at 1:30:00 is what related to my question, but in this code snippet, I will delete anything that is unrelate to the question, and the code snippet alone should provide enough context.

My parent class has name, price and quantity as the arguments.
My child class has a unique argument call "broken_phone".
The problem is centering around **repr**

This is the code that was shown in the video(exclude unrelated stuff)

```
class Item:
    all = []
    def __init__(self, name:str , price: float , quantity:int):
        #Assign to self object
        self.name = name
        self.price = price 
        self.quantity = quantity

        #action to execute
        Item.all.append(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}("{self.name}", {self.price}, {self.quantity})'

class Phone(Item):
    def __init__(self, name:str , price: float , quantity:int, broken_phone=0):
        #call to super function to have access to all attributes
        super().__init__(
            name, price, quantity
        )

        #Assign to self object
        self.name = name
        self.price = price 
        self.quantity = quantity
```

So the child class(Phone) should inherit the **repr** from the parent class(Item) as well, but when I call Phone.all, it only return
`f'{self.__class__.__name__}("{self.name}", {self.price}, {self.quantity})'`

Is it normal practice to exclude the child class argument(broken_phone)? Shouldn't the child class argument be something like this?
`f'{self.__class__.__name__}("{self.name}", {self.price}, {self.quantity}, {self.broken_phone})'`

So my question is, is this normal to exclude it like that? If not, how should I fix this. The video simply told me to just use the **repr** in parent class without fixing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this normal to exclude it like that?

Nothing is being "excluded".

`Phone` does not define its own `__repr__` method, so it uses the inherited method from `Item`, which is doing exactly what you defined it to do.  It does not know anything about a `broken_phone` attribute.

`__repr__` does not simply return all of the current instance arguments, as you seem to expect.  (And even if it did, `Phone.__init__()` does not actually save the `broken_phone` argument as an attribute.  That argument is never used.)

To fix this:

1. Assign `self.broken_phone = broken_phone` in `Phone.__init__`
2. Define `Phone.__repr__` to return your desired output.

Comment: When I said exclude, I mean we explicitly did not write a `__repr__`
for the Phone class to include "broken_phone" in the `__repr__ ` of Phone class. It's what the video didn't do. I was wondering if it is a common practice to not have a `__repr__` for a Child class.

Comment: @Clock Oh, I see.  I misunderstood what you meant.  If it's useful for the child class to return more/less/different stuff in its `__repr__` than the parent class does, then it makes sense for it to define its own `__repr__`, yes.